# $L^p$ spaces and proper inclusion

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $1≤p < q$. Prove that $L^p(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^q(\mathbb{R})$ and the inclusion is proper.

I am unsure how to begin this or even prove it about $L^p$ spaces and Banach spaces.

Comment: What is $R$? Do you mean: Let $A$ be any set, and $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$. Then $\ell^p(A) \subset \ell^q(A)$, where $\ell^p(A) = L^P(\mu)$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure on $(A, \mathcal{P}(A))$?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the exercise you should solve? Because the Statement is clearly wrong, as functions which are in $L^p$ for small $p$ are functions whose Peaks aren't to big and for big $p$ are those functions which goes to Zero fast enough

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x):= x^{-1/p} \mathbf{1}_{(1,\infty)}$. Then $f^q$ is integrable because $\frac{q}{p} > 1$. But $f^p = \frac{1}{x}$ (on $(1,\infty)$) is not.

That is, $f \in L^q(\mathbb{R})$ but $f \notin L^p(\mathbb{R}) $.

Answer (score 0):

As Frank provided a counterexample the inclusion in general doesn't hold. 
In fact if your measure is finite the inclusion is vice versa because via 
Hölder you get 
\[ \|f\|_q \leq \mu(X)^{\frac{1}{p} -\frac{1}{q}} \cdot \|f\|_p.\]
Maybe you are talking about the sequence spaces $\ell^p$ because there the inclusion holds as every function which is in $\ell^p$ converges to zero, so it will be smaller than $1$ in some cofinite set. But as $p\mapsto x^p$ is monotone decreasing for $x\in [0,1]$ you can dominate the integral (i.e. the series).